# Is it possible to send email through mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to send email using mysql. How it is possible.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test.autosendfromdrop BEFORE INSERT ON test.emaildrop
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  /* START THE WRITING OF THE EMAIL FILE HERE*/      
  SELECT  concat("To: ",NEW.To),
          concat("From: ",NEW.From),
          concat("Subject: ",NEW.Subject),
          NEW.Body
      INTO OUTFILE 
               "C:\\inetpub\\mailroot\\pickup\\mail.txt" 
          FIELDS TERMINATED by '\r\n' ESCAPED BY '';            
END;
```

Comment: (Actually, it is *possible* using a suitable UDF; but it is not to be recommended).

Comment: @arkascha Maybe post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible.

You certainly can create a file that holds content like an email does. But you cannot send an email. Because for that you have to either execute commands or communicate directly with a server. Both are out of scope for a mysql server.